# How can we add bgsound in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How can we add bgsound in wordpress, bgsound is not working

Comment: _Please_, **don't**.

Comment: Don't do this.  Background music is extremely annoying.

Comment: Take a look at this:  http://www.jatemack.com/2008/02/21/should-i-put-music-on-my-website/

Comment: 99% of non-business requirements from clients are nonsense, you're the expert - educate them.

Comment: Ditch the client if you have to. You don't want to work with a client that requires this.

Comment: sorry, bgsound is working in IE, not working in firefox.

Answer (score 6):

Edit the HTML code. After the tag < head > insert the following code:

```
<embed autostart="true" height="0" loop="true" src="URL://music-file" width="0"/>
```

**Update:**

There are three tags that are used to add sound files. Two are not valid HTML and the third doesn't work reliably across browsers:

```
<bgsound> - not a valid HTML or XHTML tag, and it only works in Internet Explorer
<embed> - not a valid HTML or XHTML tag, but it works in most browsers
<object> - a valid HTML and XHTML tag, but it only works in Safari
```

**Note:** Your situation may be different, but it is usually a very bad idea to add music as a background to a web page. Having music playing in the background can interrupt whatever is currently coming through the users speakers.  Many people use their computers as media stations that play music and video.  Having this suddenly interrupted is the equivalent of having a newspaper that jumps off the table and wraps around your head like a facehugger and starts laying headlines in your throat.

Also having music playing will decrease the performance of the site, especially on slower machines.

Comment: You forgot the "don't" before the word "insert".

Comment: I know no one's really wild about this question, but that doesn't mean we need to downvote people who provide informative answers to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Do it in the header file of your theme (header.php).

Comment: i have add in header.php of theme

Comment: First check that the code you added are actually sent to the web browser (view source). If that's the case, update your question with the code you're using.